# docker -P not exposing ports of application started as argument

Tags: linux, docker

I'd like to start a container with an argument to start a server inside the container. The problem is the -P switch is not exposing the ports of this server to my host.

```
docker run -it -e "JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_45" -e "CARBON_HOME=/opt/IOT/wso2iots-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" -P ubuntupreped:2.0 /bin/sh /opt/IOT/wso2iots-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/bin/wso2server.sh
```

When I build a image exposing the env variables and a script to start the server, the -P switch works as expected.

Any idea whats happening here?

Comment: Did you [expose](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) the ports in your Dockerfile?

Comment: you either specify the port exposed in the dockerfile and let the -P bind them or you bind them manually with -p connect_To_This_Port:container_Port